# Adding column in different collection

Tags: python, mongodb

How can i copy one column from one collection to another collection in mongoDB using Python?

Answer (score 0):

document:`{
  _id: Object_ID
  username: "john"
  email: "john@email.com"
  age: 24
}`

Now, you want to copy username column from this document of some `collection1` to a document of `collection2`, for that,

let say you have build connection with MongoDB, and we use `db` object to further data manipulation.

1. we need to get that intended column data with column name

   `data = db.collection1.find_one(
     {"email": "john@email.com"},
     {"username": 1}
   )`
   // now `data` is a python dictionary contains value of username on key `username`
2. now we are going to create a new document in another collection(or we can update that data based on some condition if you wish)

   `db.users.collection2.insert_one(data)` //hence we got our new document with that data in collection2

Now here I use `find_one` to exactly collect a single data, but if you need to collect a list of data then, just iterate through the list while inserting those data into a collection.

Comment: And can you please elaborate that find_many  or list of data how to handle..?

Comment: when you use `data = db.collection1.find({"email": "john@email.com"},
  {"username": 1})`. It gives you a list of dictionary. so all you have to do make a loop like, `for d in data` and within it you pass `db.users.collection2.insert_one(d)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach with find to get all documents you want and then save to new record.
Taking the same document example

```
{  
  username: "john",
  email: "john@email.com",
  age: 24
}
```

You can try this

```
db.collection_name.find({ username:"john" },{ _id: 0, username: 1 }).forEach((res) => { db.new_collection_name.insert(res); })
```